# Error when pushing to existing scratch org

Tags: metadata, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I keep getting the error

> Cannot set sharingModel to ControlledByParent on a CustomObject without a MasterDetail relationship field

when pushing to an existing scratch org. After doing some research I have found that this is a known issue and the workaround is to add the master-detail lookup field to the deployment (even if it has not changed) to your deployment selected list.

My question is how do I do this in Salesforce DX? It seems like I need to push the Master object as well but Im not sure how to do that without making a change to the file. I have found that I can change the relationship to ReadWrite and it will push but then will fail when pushing to a new scratch org since it is suppose to be ControlledByParent.

Has anyone figured this issue out in DX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering I actually found a fix to that error. You just need to go to the Master objects meta file and add a space to the bottom. This will deploy both of the objects therefore fixing the error. This seems like a hack but it works.

If anyone knows anymore info about this issue or another way to fix it please post it!